# SimpleCursorAdapter with ListView visibility

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

Hello I created a database in which I am trying to list the names of that database in a listview but nothing is showing up.

The code for mty database is:

```
public class LockedInDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "Locked In";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public LockedInDatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ARTISTS (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                    + "NAME TEXT,"
                    + "INTRO TEXT,"
                    +"IMAGE_RESCOURCE_ID INT)");
        insertArtist(db, "Jinx Inkz", "An artist who specializes in portraits and custom pieces", R.drawable.jinx_profile);
        insertArtist(db, "Bazooka Zook", "An artist who specializes in clean line work and neo - traditional", R.drawable.zook_profile );

            }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    private static void insertArtist(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, String intro, int resourceId){
        ContentValues artistInfo = new ContentValues();
        artistInfo.put("NAME", name);
        artistInfo.put("INTRO", intro);
        artistInfo.put("IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID", resourceId);
        db.insert("ARTISTS",null, artistInfo);
    }

}
```

finally the java code for where I want the info to appear is

```
public class ArtistsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Cursor cursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_artists);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ListView listArtists = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.artistsLV);
    SQLiteOpenHelper lockedInDatabaseHelper = new LockedInDatabaseHelper(ArtistsActivity.this);
    try {
        db = lockedInDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.query("ARTISTS",
                new String[]{"_id", "NAME"},
                null, null, null, null, null);
        SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(ArtistsActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                cursor,
                new String[]{"NAME"},
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1},
                0);
        listArtists.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Database unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

    }

    //Create a listener for clicks on listview
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener =
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listArtists,
                                View itemView,
                                int position,
                                long id){
            //Pass tha artist user clicks on to artistActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(ArtistsActivity.this, ArtistDetail.class);
            intent.putExtra(ArtistDetail.EXTRA_ARTISTID, (int) id);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    };
    //Assign the listener to list view
    listArtists.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    }
}
```

I have been going over the code a lot but I don't think it has to do with the ListView. Please help! I am super stuck and I just want a list that I can add an onClickListener to in order to contiue the app.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you have mis-spelt the column name **IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID**. That is you create the table using the column name **IMAGE_RESCOURCE_ID** but try to insert into column **IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID**.

I'd suggest always using constants for table and columns names and thus you define them once and subsequently use the same constant to refer to the items.

As such I'd suggest changing the Database helper **LockedInDatabaseHelper.java** to :-

```
public class LockedInDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "Locked In";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TBL_ARTISTS = "ARTISTS";
    public static final String COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COl_NAME = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_INTRO = "INTRO";
    public static final String COL_IMAGERESOURCEID = "IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID";

    public LockedInDatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ARTISTS (" + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + COl_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + COL_INTRO + " TEXT,"
                + COL_IMAGERESOURCEID + " INT)");
        insertArtist(db, "Jinx Inkz", "An artist who specializes in portraits and custom pieces", R.drawable.jinx_profile);
        insertArtist(db, "Bazooka Zook", "An artist who specializes in clean line work and neo - traditional",R.drawable.zook_profile);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    private static void insertArtist(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, String intro, int resourceId){
        ContentValues artistInfo = new ContentValues();
        artistInfo.put(COl_NAME, name);
        artistInfo.put(COL_INTRO, intro);
        artistInfo.put(COL_IMAGERESOURCEID, resourceId);
        db.insert(TBL_ARTISTS,null, artistInfo);
    }
}
```

Along with some changes to the **ArtistsActivity.java** to also utilise the constants so that it incorporates :-

```
cursor = db.query(LockedInDatabaseHelper.TBL_ARTISTS,
                    new String[]{LockedInDatabaseHelper.COL_ID, "NAME"},
                    null, null, null, null, null);
            SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(ArtistsActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    cursor,
                    new String[]{LockedInDatabaseHelper.COl_NAME},
                    new int[] {android.R.id.text1},
                    0);
```

I believe that the above will work. **However, as you are changing the structure of the  database then you should do 1 of the following before rerunning the App** :-

1. Delete/Clear the App's data (this effectively deletes the database).
2. Uninstall the App (this also effectively deletes the database).